# Creating a connection pool using all nodes in AWS opensearch cluster

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, opensearch, connection-pool

I am using OpenSearch.Net client to connect to AWS  opensearch. I want to use multiple nodes in a connection pool by following [the example in this doc](https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-net/blob/main/USER_GUIDE.md), but I would like to get the nodes through the [/nodes API](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/api-reference/nodes-apis/nodes-info/). However, it seems that we have to manually pass in all the nodes, like this:

```
var nodes = new Uri[]
{
    new Uri("http://myserver1:9200"),
    new Uri("http://myserver2:9200"),
    new Uri("http://myserver3:9200")
};

var pool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
var client = new OpenSearchClient(settings);
```

So I would like to make use of the /node API to get all the nodes and then pass it to the connection pool object. Obviously I can't do eat easily because in order to call the /node API, I will have to connect to AWS opensearch in the first place (chicken and egg).

Is there a way around this? How can I create a connection pool based on the existing nodes of my opensearch cluster?